# Extending Enum in Ada

Tags: enums, ada

Is it possible to extend an Enum type in Ada?
if I have for example:

```
type ABC_Type is (A, B, C);
```

Now I want new type ABCDE_Type that will include everything that ABC_Type has and Also (D, E).
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot extend an Enum type in Ada, you can only create derivations/subtypes that cover a subset of the original one.

You have to do it the other way round:

```
type ABCDE_Type is (A, B, C, D, E);
type ABC_Type is new ABCDE_Type range A .. C;
-- or
subtype ABC_Type is ABCDE_Type range A .. C;
```

Comment: Thank you. They screwed up with that. If you inherit from a type and you want to extend the enum it's not possible....

Comment: You know, I'm going to have to disagree with that. I don't think they did mess up with that. This is perhaps the biggest disservice that OOP has done to programming: making people think that everything should be extensible. The subtyping concept in Ada is incredibly elegant if you consider that enumerations (and other numerics) should be most general at the 'Base and more specialized with each derivation. Thus you can have IEE745, then subtype a Float as being IEEE745'Range thereby removing nonnormal representations and allowing your Float operations to assume that the value is numeric.

Comment: You can only extend composite types. Maybe this graphic helps understanding: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ada_types.png - otherwise you might wonder why you can't extend `Positive` to `Integer`, only shrink the range.

Comment: @Shark8 - Quite. The whole point of putting strong typing on things like enumerations and numeric types is to force you to actually put some thought into your program's typing system and boundry conditions. The ability to just expand or shrink the defintions willy-nilly would totally defeat that.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. I disagree with you. One of the principles of OOP calls inheritance: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) Ada is too restrictive in that issue. If for example I have an Animal class witch has enumeration member calls characteristics. I would want the Animal class to include (survivability) and for the derived class Fox I would want the characteristics to include (survivability, cunning) and unfortunately its **not possible** in Ada. When I am creating a **new** type, I dont harm the base type i.e strong typing preserves.

Comment: @Yony – Yes you can use inheritance in Ada; you just have to use tagged types. {This actually reflects two different modes of thinking about problems, each more suited to different problems.} I'll type up some examples and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by oneone is correct; you cannot extend enumeration (or numeric) types.
You **can** however extend tagged types, using Yony's Animal/Fox example I've translated it into Ada's OO-model:

```
-- Percent defines an integer-value between zero and one-hundred, inclusive.
Subtype Percent is Natural Range 0..100;

-- Attribute defines an integer between one and ten, inclusive.
Subtype Attribute is Positive Range 1..10;

-- Animal, the base object-class.
Type Animal is Abstract Tagged Record
-- All Animals have a survivability attribute.
Survivability : Percent:= Percent'Last; -- Default "survivability" to Max.
End Record;

-----------------------------------------------------
-- Declaration of Primitive Operations for Animal. --
-----------------------------------------------------

-- Name; returns the name of the type of the animal.
Function Name( Object : In Animal'Class ) Return String;


-------------------------------------------------------
-- Implementation of Primitive Operations for Animal --
-------------------------------------------------------

Function Name( Object : In Animal'Class ) Return String is
Use Ada.Tags;
begin
    -- This is implementation dependent; with the compiler I'm using the Uppercased 
    -- type-name of the actual object will be returned.
Return External_Tag(Object'Tag);
end Name;

---------------------------
-- The Fox object-class. --
---------------------------
Type Fox is New Animal with record
Cunning : Attribute:= Attribute'First;
end record;
```

In fact, both extension (OO-inheritance) and exclusion (subtyping) can be used in the same program, and the same subprograms operating on a type.

```
package Windowing is
Type Window is tagged private;

-- Pointers for windows.
Type Window_Pointer is Access Window'Class; -- Normal pointer
Subtype Handle is Not Null Window_Pointer;  -- Pointer with Null excluded.

-- A light 'vector' of handles.
Type Window_List is Array (Positive Range <>) of Handle;

-- Primitive operations
Function Get_Child_Windows( Object : In Handle ) Return Window_List;
Procedure Set_Window_Height( Object : In Handle; Height : In Positive );
Function  Get_Window_Height( Object : In Handle ) Return Positive;

-- more primitive operations... including subprograms to create windows 
    -- and perhaps assign them as children.

Private
Package Win_Vectors is new
  Ada.Containers.Vectors(Index_Type => Positive, Element_Type => Handle);

Type Window is Tagged Record
    -- X & Y may be negative, or zero.
    X, Y        : Integer:= Positive'First;
    -- Height & Width must be positive.
    Height, Width   : Positive:=    Positive'First;
    -- Child-list
    Children        : Win_Vectors.Vector:= Win_Vectors.Empty_Vector;
End Record;


End Windowing;

package body Windowing is
Procedure Set_Window_Height( Object : In Handle; Height : In Positive ) is
begin
    Object.Height:= Set_Window_Height.Height;
end Set_Window_Height;

Function  Get_Window_Height( Object : In Handle ) Return Positive is
begin
    Return Object.Height;
end Get_Window_Height;

Function Get_Child_Windows ( Object : In Handle ) Return Window_List is
begin
    -- Return a null-array if there are no child windows.
    if Object.Children.Is_Empty then
      Return (2..1 => Object);
    end if;

    -- Create an array of the proper size, then initialize to self-referential
    -- handle to avoid null-exclusion error.
    Return Result : Window_List( 1..Positive(Object.Children.Length) ):= 
         (others => Object) do
    Declare
         Procedure Assign_Handle(Position : Win_Vectors.Cursor) is
          Use Win_Vectors;
          Index : Positive:= To_Index( Position );
         begin
          Result(Index):= Element(Position);
         end Assign_Handle;
    Begin
         -- Replace the self-referential handles with the correct ones.
         Object.Children.Iterate( Process => Assign_Handle'Access );
    End;
    End Return;
end Get_Child_Windows;


end Windowing;
```

Subtyping itself can be be a powerful concept on its own. Indeed when modeling mathematics, Ada's subtypings can allow functions to exactly match their mathematical definitions, or implement things in such a way that certain checks are completely unnessacary.

```
-- Remove non-normal representations.
Subtype Real is Float Range Float'Range;

-- Constrain to non-negative numbers.
Subtype Natural_Real is Real Range 0.0 .. Real'Last; 

-- Because of the parameter-type, we do not need to implement any checks
-- for negative numbers in the subprogram body.
Function Square_Root( X : In Natural_Real ) Return Natural_Real;

-- Because Divisor is positive, we need not worry about ddivide-by-zero.
Function Good_Divide( Quotient: Integer; Divisor: Positive ) Return Natural;
```

Comment: You're welcome; I added a little at the end to show subtyping on its own.